# Error:undefined intent constructor when start service in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm try to start service in the activity.But it shows error like "The constructor Intent(SampleService, MyService) is undefined"

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public static boolean isInstanceCreated() { 
      return instance != null; 
   }

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

     instance = this;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    instance = null;

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

Starting service from SampleService.java

```
  public class SampleService extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_activity);
    Intent myintent =new Intent(SampleService.this,MyService.this);//Error show here..
    startService(myintent);
      }
 }
```

Service initialized in manifest file.

```
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.MyApp.MyService" />
```

Help me to solve the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not `Service.this` you have to pass class
so change like this..

```
Intent myintent =new Intent(SampleService.this,MyService.Class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
 Intent myintent =new Intent(SampleService.this,MyService.this);
```

to

```
 Intent myintent =new Intent(SampleService.this,MyService.Class);
 // first param is a context second param is a class in your case a MyServiceClass
```

Look at the public constructors at you do not have a constructor as `Intent(SampleService, MyService)` .You have wrong params for the intent constructor.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

```
public Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)

Added in API level 1
Create an intent for a specific component. All other fields (action, data, type, class) are null, though they can be modified later with explicit calls. This provides a convenient way to create an intent that is intended to execute a hard-coded class name, rather than relying on the system to find an appropriate class for you; see setComponent(ComponentName) for more information on the repercussions of this.

Parameters
packageContext  A Context of the application package implementing this class.
cls

The component class that is to be used for the intent.
```

Comment: You're late ... with a couple of seconds :)

Comment: @gunar yes about 20 secondslate